# Is there a performance difference between using angular $filter and the Filter suffixed name?

Tags: angularjs, performance, filter

The documentation mentions 2 ways of calling filters from controllers and services, which are for a currency filter :

```
$filter('currency')
```

or

```
currencyFilter
```

By looking at the source code of angular, I see that the first one calls the injector with the name + suffix to give it back. That said, for a intense use of filter or a filter(s) that is called very often, could this have a performance impact ?
My thinking is that if you inject it through the 2 way, you then have the reference to the filter function and can use it directly. Whereas, in the 1st way, the injector would be called every time you need to use the filter.

Lets say you'd put it in a watcher that is called often, Im feeling a possible perf drain here.
Any input on that ? Jsperf seems to be down till they release v2 but maybe someone already has an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that `$filter` does is [getting a service from injector](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/ng/filter.js#L136-L138). Injector overhead is negligible.

This concern can be considered preliminary optimization. There are places in the application that are more critical for performance and require more attention.

If the filter is used for many watchers or digests may be triggered many times per second, this provides more obvious bottleneck and a point for optimization than a way how the filter is being applied.

Comment: Yep for sure, there are other bottlenecks to investigate and of course I did look at the angular source code before asking. This was simply a matter of curiosity and I was hoping to get some perf comparison or something like that

Comment: After service instantiation `$injector.get` just [reads cache object property](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/auto/injector.js#L812-L818), so this should be the least of your concerns. Btw, you can set up local jsperf [v1](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsperf.com) or [v2](https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com) copy.